# Create custom Lists i.e. Abbreviations and add these to the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, lists, listingsutf8

I'm currently encountering the problem that, I need to create Lists of Abbreviatings and Code Listings ( yes Listings List is in Lyx, but it wont compile if I add it ).

Is there a possibility to create custom lists and importantly, add these to the TOC ?

If at all possible, I would prefer a Lyx Solution, without having to fall back to Tex Code.

Thanks in advance.